# 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list of sentences called s2
I would like to lower the words that it contains and split all the sentences into words.
I try like this :

```
s2 = s2_s.lower().split()
```

But I got an error message :

```
'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: isn't it obvious from the error that your `s2_s` is already a list? try `print(s2_s)`

Comment: @AshishRanjan, s2_s is a list of sentences.

Comment: please update the question with sample input and expected output, btw list doesn't have any lower or split methods

Comment: @DavidG how can I change it into string?

Comment: You have a list that contains strings. Try looping through your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to loop through every value of your list and call `.lower().split()` on each of the values:

```
s2 = [s.lower().split() for s in s2_s]
```

Comment: thank you, when I try your code , i got this result : [[, 'material', 'breach'], ['acme’s', 'failure', 'to', 'comply', 'with', 'any', 'of', 'the', 'provisions', 'of', 'exhibit', 'c', 'may', 'constitute', 'a', 'material', 'breach', 'of', 'the', 'master', 'agreement', 'which', 'is', 'subject', 'to', 'the', 'provisions', 'of', 'section', '113a', 'of', 'the', 'agreement'], []]  Whay there is [] in the end?

Comment: @Nasri It's really impossible to say what causes that, without seeing what your input list looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply lower function on list. Lower function can be apply on string. 
You can use list comprehension on list.

```
>>>s2=['AB','ab','d','k']
>>> s2=[x.lower() for x in s2]
>>> s2
['ab', 'ab', 'd', 'k']
```

Comment: OP got list of sentences not words

Answer (score -1):

using  `lambda`

```
list_of_sent =[] # your list
sol = list(map(lambda x : x.lower().split(' '), list_of_sent))
```